# Question about modular arithmetic equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

In the book I am reading there is a section about modular arithmetic and modular equations.

First, here is what is stated in the book:

> **Theorem:** Given the equation $ax \equiv b \mod n$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $d := \gcd(a,n)$.
>
> 1. If $\gcd(a,n) \nmid b$, then the equations has no solution.
> 2. If $\gcd(a,n) \mid b$, chose $y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ya+zn=d$. Then the above equation is equivalent to  $x \equiv y \frac{b}{d} \pmod{\frac{n}{d}}$
>
> **Corollary:** Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $ma \equiv mb \pmod n$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$
> implies that $a \equiv b \pmod n$.
>
> We want to solve two simultaneous modular arithmetic equations:
>
> $cx \equiv a \pmod n$ and $dx \equiv b \pmod m$.
>
> Because of the Theorem above, we can assume without restrictions that
> $c=d=1$.

**My Questions:**

1. I do not really understand why we have to/ or should want to solve both of the equations $cx \equiv a \pmod n$ and $dx \equiv b \pmod m$. Normally I would just solve $cx \equiv a \pmod n$ for $x$ and then we already know the solution $x$ of $dx \equiv b \pmod m$.
2. My second question is regarding the statement that we can assume $c=d=1$ without "restrictions". I do not really understand why the Theorem implies that. I also do not understand what is meant with "without restrictions". Is it used here in the same sense as "without loss of generality"?

Comment: The point is to solve them *simultaneously*.  That is, you are looking for some integer $x$ that satisfies *both* congruences.

Comment: @lulu Okey, I did an example. And I think that I got the simultaneous part. Do you know why we can assume that $c=d=1$?

Comment: Well, if $\gcd(c,n)=1=\gcd(d,m)$ then you can just multiply by the modular inverse.  Otherwise, use the Theorem to reduce to that special case.

Comment: @lulu Well, it was not mentioned that we can assume that $gcd(c,n)=1=gcd(d,m)$. How can I use the Theorem to reduce it to that case?

Comment: @lulu Oh wait, did you mean to just find the equivalent equations as stated in the theorem?

Comment: Yes.  The Theorem shows that the general problem can be reduced to the relatively prime case.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much!